# wxPython listctrl insertitem and SetItem all at once

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I have a listctrl,

```
    self.list = wx.ListCtrl(panel, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.LC_NO_HEADER)
    self.list.InsertColumn(col=0, heading='', format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTER, width=150)
    self.list.InsertColumn(col=1, heading='', format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTER, width=450)

    for person in people:
        #this is the issue right here
        index = self.list.InsertItem(0, person.age) #one line to insert an item and get the index, and the next line to update the item at that index... two lines to actually put a full entry in.  
        self.list.SetItem(index=index, column=1, label=person.name)
```

This works fine setting up the listctrl initially in the constructor, but what if I want to dynamically add/remove items in the listctrl at runtime?

I've come across wx.CallAfter, wx.CallLater, startWorker (from wx.lib.delayedresult), and wx.Timer

If you look at the example above the issue is that I've got one line that inserts the item, and another line that updates the item to have the correct name on the item that was just inserted.  So if I've got threads that are taking turns removing and adding items to the listctrl, if I insert an item and another thread inserts an item at the same time, the index that I just got won't be relevant for updating.  i.e. I need an atomic operation for inserting an item that includes inserting both the person's age and the person's name. So my first question is, is there a way to insert all information of a list item in one line?

If I cannot do that, then my next question is how could I accomplish the prescribed behavior? For example, suppose there are threads randomly coloring the top row, adding, and deleting:

```
    self.color_timer = wx.Timer(self)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.item_colorizer, self.color_timer)
    self.red_shown = True
    self.color_timer.Start(500)

    self.delete_timer = wx.Timer(self)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.item_deleter, self.delete_timer)
    self.delete_timer.Start(500)


    self.adder_timer = wx.Timer(self)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.item_queuer, self.adder_timer)
    self.adder_timer.Start(400)
```

Then here are my methods that are used to add people, delete people, and color the top row:

```
def item_queuer(self, event):
    startWorker(consumer=self.item_adder,
                    workerFn=self.person_generator)


def person_generator(self):
    return {'person':random.choice(people)}

def item_adder(self, result):
    res = result.get()
    person = res['person']
    wx.CallAfter(self.list.InsertItem, 0, person.name) # this is the problem right here.  If another thread does a color swap in between this line and the next, then this won't work. 
    wx.CallAfter(self.list.SetItem, index=0, column=1, label=person.name)

def item_deleter(self, event):
    wx.CallAfter(self.list.DeleteItem, 0)

def item_colorizer(self, event):
    if self.color_timer.IsRunning():
        if not self.red_shown:
            wx.CallAfter(self.list.SetItemBackgroundColour, 0, wx.RED)
            wx.CallAfter(self.list.SetItemTextColour, 0, wx.WHITE)
            self.red_shown = True
        else:
            wx.CallAfter(self.list.SetItemBackgroundColour, 0, wx.BLUE)
            wx.CallAfter(self.list.SetItemTextColour, 0, wx.BLACK)
            self.red_shown = False
```

What actually happens when I run this is that I end up having rows where the person is partially inserted (just the age), and the color changes before the name is inserted.  I've noticed that the InsertItem method on the listctrl is overloaded and offers one signature where I can insert a ListItem, but I cannot get that to work either.

```
    item1 = wx.ListItem()
    item1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.GREEN)
    item1.SetColumn(0)
    item1.SetText(32)
    item1.SetColumn(1)
    item1.SetText('John')
    self.list.InsertItem(item1)
```

wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "rv != -1" failed at ....\src\msw\listctrl.cpp(1730) in wxListCtrl::InsertItem(): failed to insert an item in wxListCtrl